# BQ API: Querying external data source (Google Sheets / Drive)

Tags: python-3.x, google-bigquery

I'm using [BQ PY Client Libraries](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/bigquery/usage.html#run-a-query-using-a-named-query-parameter) to query a BQ table. However the table links to external data source - Google Sheets

Here's my code:

1)
generate credentials (specifying additional scope to access Google Sheets resources - as per [this](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/issues/3067#issuecomment-299518364))

```
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
credentials, _ = google.auth.default(scopes=SCOPES)
client = bq.Client(credentials=credentials)

query = 'SELECT * FROM `ext_tbl.sheets`'
```

2)
Insert a query job: `client.query(query)`

3)
fetch results: `job.result()`

and get following error:

> google.api_core.exceptions.NotFound: 404 Not found: Files
>   /gdrive/id/1Y74S3YIeEu5OL2UPrOGLCrH7AZOFXgt6Z2AuZ-s6Kac

Comment: This error should be related with Google Sheets URL you are providing. [Here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/blob/db7fef8129ce26013886324cf51f7b526078d702/docs/bigquery/snippets.py#L2748) you have the full example how to query to Google Sheets. Can you double check the steps here with your code?

Comment: Thanks a lot! Made my day, too stupid of me .. it works now :)